# Can letting anyone create Dockerfiles result in RCE?

Tags: attack-vector, docker

I'm about to build a web service that can be notified by Git that a push to a particular branch happened. Once this is done, the branch is checked out and `docker build -t somename .` happens. Is it secure or am I basically letting anyone run arbitrary commands as root on this server?

Comment: is `docker build -t somename .` running as root?

Comment: @amccormack: to the best of my knowledge, it has to.

Comment: Where does the `somename` file come from? Is it pulled from git?

Comment: @NeilSmithline: we can say it's hardcoded.

Comment: @NeilSmithline: why do you ask? I'd certainly not allow `somename="foo; rm -rf; "`

Comment: I'm trying to understand who can control the contents of the file.

Comment: Dockerfile? Anyone with access to the Git repo, which are org members. Not all of them have equal privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Your concern is indeed appropriate. The attacker can share system resources with his attack container as it is a Dockerfile you provide him and not just a Docker container. The build command of the Dockerfile can mount any part of the server filesystem and access any port available to the server. Not a good plan.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be okay if I built the files in a separate VM and deployed to hub?

Comment: If you want security, deploy the Dockerfile inside a VM.

Comment: If you used DockerHub to do an automatic build on your GitHub Dockerfile and deployed that DockerHub built image instead then you eliminate the possibilities of a local Dockerfile build accessing system resources directly.  Docker is not designed (not yet at least) as a secure solution so there would still be risk but it would be greatly reduced.